# adjust column width size using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm facing trouble in adjusting column width of the below excel file. I'm using this code.

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

ws.delete_cols(1)   #remove col 'A' which has pandas index no.

for column in ws.iter_cols():
    name = get_column_letter(column[0].column)
    new_col_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column)
    #ws.column_dimensions[name].bestFit = True    #I tried this but the result is same
    ws.column_dimensions[name].width = new_col_length
```

excel sheet:
[image: original file]

the output im getting.:
[image: result]

Comment: I suspect the merged cells might be a problem here. You should really run some tests for individual columns to see why the values are being set as they are. NB you can use `cell.column_letter`

Comment: The problem is the deletion of Column A at the start (or at any point). Openpyxl doesn't adjust the location of merged cells on insert or deletion of columns or rows. E.g. it looks like cells D1 and E1 are merged for value 'Aug-22', when col A is deleted this would become cells C1 and D1 however openpyxl keeps the original merge so D1 and E1 remain merged and the value 'Apr-22' in F1 is deleted as it is now part of the merge. Disable the col A deletion and the sheet will probably be as you want (albeit still with the pandas indexes). To delete the column you'll need to handle the merged cells

Comment: @moken you got it right. deletion of col A was the problem.

Comment: If you can and wish to do so; xlwings can do this with two commands; **ws.range('A:A').api.Delete()** and **ws.autofit(axis="columns")** along with opening and saving the workbook of course.

Comment: To go back to the original issue of the panda index needing to be deleted. If you have control over the production of the excel book and it doesn't affect anything else, adding **index=False** to the **df.to_excel()** command should prevent the index being written in the first place.

Comment: @moken I tried it too. I got the following error.--> `NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.`

Comment: @moken anyways, your solution solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should manage the deletion of column A using Openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

path = 'col_width.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

remerge_cells_list = []

# Remove existing merged cells, and
# Add the calculated new cell coords to remerge_cells_list to re-add after
# the deletion of column A.
for unmerge in range(len(ws.merged_cells.ranges)):
    current_merge = ws.merged_cells.ranges[0]
    new_min_col = get_column_letter(current_merge.min_col-1)
    new_max_col = get_column_letter(current_merge.max_col-1)
    remerge_cells_list.append(new_min_col + str(current_merge.min_row) + ':'
                              + new_max_col + str(current_merge.max_row))
    print("Removing merge: " + current_merge.coord)
    ws.unmerge_cells(current_merge.coord)

print("\nDeleting column A\n")
ws.delete_cols(1)   #remove col 'A' which has pandas index no.

# Set the column width dimenions
for column in ws.iter_cols():
    name = get_column_letter(column[0].column)
    new_col_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column)
    # ws.column_dimensions[name].bestFit = True    #I tried this but the result is same
    ws.column_dimensions[name].width = new_col_length+2 # Added a extra bit for padding

# Re-merge the cells from the remerge_cells_list
# Don't think it matters if this is done before or after resizing the columns
for merge in remerge_cells_list:
    print("Add adjusted cell merge: " + merge)
    ws.merge_cells(merge)

wb.save('col_width_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: Why cast the column letter to a string?

Comment: You can simplify a lot of the rest of the code using the API. No need to unmerge then merge, just use the CellRange methods for shifting. `values_only` means you don't need to call `.value`

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research finally, I found it.

NOTE : In the below code, **sheet** is the worksheet name. Usually in the documentation, we can see it as **ws**. Please don't forget to change the worksheet name.

```
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

UPDATE : This code doesn't work for all, but don't hesitate to try it..